# Visual Studio 2012: Intellisense not working for <ext tags

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, intellisense, ext.net

Visual Studio 2012 intellisense is not working for markup code and `<ext tags`, it's only showing `html tags` recommendations. 
How I can make it to work?

**ext.net settings in web.config**

```
<configuration>   
       <configSections>

        <section name="extnet" type="Ext.Net.GlobalConfig" requirePermission="false" />    </configSections>       <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
          <add name="DirectRequestModule" preCondition="managedHandler" type="Ext.Net.DirectRequestModule, Ext.Net" />
        </modules>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
        <handlers>
          <add name="DirectRequestHandler" verb="*" path="*/ext.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="Ext.Net.ResourceHandler" />
        </handlers>   
     </system.webServer>
<pages>
  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
    <add namespace="Ext.Net" />
  </namespaces>
  <controls>
    <add assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" tagPrefix="webopt" />
    <add assembly="Ext.Net" namespace="Ext.Net" tagPrefix="ext" />
  </controls>
</pages>
```

Comment: We will have to take a look at your web.config and sample page. You are using web forms or mvc?

Comment: @Peska Web Forms, is there any specific part of the web.config that you would like to see? Because there are many Settings

Comment: All related to ext.net.

Comment: @Peska I updated my post

Comment: Try to add this: `<%@ Register Assembly="Ext.Net" Namespace="Ext.Net" TagPrefix="ext" %>` just below your @Page directive.

Comment: @Peska its already there... It used to work but I dont know why it stopped

Comment: @aggicd, if you create a new Web Forms application, does this issue persists or not? If only this page have this issue, please try to clean solution or restart VS and reopen this project again.

Comment: @SaraLiu-MSFT I tried loading another `ext.net` project but the issue persists, so I guess its something with VS